# Cast of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'CFReadStreamRef *' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation, foundation, multiple-indirection

I want to  use `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost` with `NSInput`- and `OutputStream`s. I have two ivars `NSInputStream *_inputStream` and `NSOutputStream *_outputStream`.

The following gives me two error messages:

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL,
  (__bridge_retained CFStringRef)self.hostname, self.port,
  (CFReadStreamRef *)&_inputStream, (CFWriteStreamRef *)&_outputStream);
```

> error: cast of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to '`CFReadStreamRef *`' (aka '`struct __CFReadStream **`') is disallowed with ARC
>   error: cast of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to '`CFWriteStreamRef *`' (aka '`struct __CFWriteStream **`') is disallowed with ARC

How would I fix this? I tried using `__bridge` but I got similar error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a pointer to actual `CFReadStreamRef` and `CFWriteStreamRef` variables, then cast when assigning to your NSTypes. Basically:

```
CFThingRef cfThing = NULL;
CFFunctionGetThing(&cfThing);
NSThing * nsThing = cfThing;
```

Of course, you'll have to add the appropriate bridge cast and do all appropriate reference count ops for `cfThing`.

Comment: Is this the only way to do this?

Comment: @WTP Not sure - I've not spent much time with ARC to date. Wrap it! :)

Comment: @WTP: Don't forget that the function will zap the previous content of _inputStream and _outputStream with its own new CRStreamRefs, so you might as well make them CFStreamRefs.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what ARC is doing, and what __bridge casts do: ARC takes responsibility for retaining / releasing NSObjects. __bridge casts transfer that responsibility. For example, __bridge_retained retains an NSString, cast the pointer to CFStringRef, and handed the responsibility for doing the matching release operation to whoever uses the CFStringRef.

*That* cannot possibly work with a pointer to an NSObject* or a pointer to a Core Foundation ref. A pointer points to a memory location. Any kind of NSObject* or Core Foundation object could be stored there.

You need two variables, one for an NSInputStream* and one for a CFReadStreamRef. Use the appropriate bridge cast to move the NSInputStream* to the CFReadStreamRef. Now you have what you want, and can pass the address on.